# Largest known prime maximizing the relative digitsum?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, big-numbers

A prime number with a given number of digits (except $1$) has the maximum possible digitsum (in base $10$) , if it has only digits nine except one digit which is $8$.

> A large (probable) prime of this kind is , according to OEIS , $$10^{2\cdot 188484}-10^{188484}-1$$ Is it the largest known such prime number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is website with Near-repdigit-related (probable) prime numbers.
It's number 82 in the list there:
https://stdkmd.net/nrr/prime/#list_size

Comment: This is $$10^{1888529} - 10^{944264} - 1$$ Thank you